# Showing Expired Entries Only. Not working

Tags: conditionals

I want to show previous concerts (past concerts) under a special tab. I only want to show past concerts, not current or upcoming concerts that is under a different tab. I tried the following code. Using EE 2.x

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="concerts" sort="desc" limit="20" show_expired="yes" }

  {if expiration_date < current_time}

  {concert-info}

  {/if}

  {/exp:channel:entries}
```

This does not work it shows both upcoming concerts and past concerts. I double checked and the past concerts have an expired dates and they have expired.

Comment: Can you not just include  the `stop_before=` tag and set that tag to now ? https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#id62

Comment: I added to the channel:entries tag:  stop_before="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'} Still show upcoming shows and past show both. Only want past shows.

Comment: Try adding `parse="inward"` to the end of your opening channel:entries tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use condition like a below:

```
{if expiration_date < current_time AND expiration_date!=""}
```

Alternatively,you can use below query to get the records:

```
SELECT
    t.entry_id,
    t.title,
    t.url_title,
    d.field_id_XX AS your_custom_field
FROM
    exp_channels AS c NATURAL JOIN
    exp_channel_titles AS t NATURAL JOIN
    exp_channel_data AS d
WHERE
    c.channel_id = your_channel_id AND
    t.expiration_date != 0 AND
    t.expiration_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Comment: There has to be an easier way than this.  This is way over my head.

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Not working, still shows upcoming concerts and expired concerts both. I want to show only past concerts. Reminder I am using EE 2.10.1.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my original comment, it turns out you can use shorthand as well as long format.

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel= "mychannel"
  start_on = "-12 months"
  stop_before= "yesterday"
  show_expired = "yes"
  ...
}
```

This will look back 12 mths until yesterday.

Comment: Does NOT work. reminder I am using EE 2.10.1.  Can you use shorthand in EE 2.x

Comment: According to the docs it is supported: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#id59